# How to change passive present continuous tense to its infinitive form? "The meal is being cooked" to "I heard the sound of the meal being cooked"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, infinitives

Eg: *The meal is being cooked.*

if we say

1- *I heard the sound of the meal being cooked*, then people may interpret as "*I heard the sound of the meal that is cooked*" and we lost its continuous meaning

2- *I heard the sound of the meal being being cooked*, the sentence is weird.

**How to change passive present continuous tense to its infinitive form?**

Comment: It's the cook moving pots and pans around in the kitchen that makes the noise - the meal doesn't (well, apart from sizzling!), so I don't think anyone would misinterpret the sentence.

Comment: The distinction of continuous/non-continuous is not available in non-finite forms.

Comment: What about “I heard the meal cooking”, or “I heard X cooking the meal”?

Comment: There's no infinitive. You mean participle.

Answer (score 1):

I think your understanding of point #1 is actually incorrect.  The sentence:

> I heard the sound of the meal being cooked.

would be interpreted by most people to mean "I heard a sound" and "the sound was produced by the activity the meal being cooked".  (I heard somebody cooking it)

If instead, you actually wanted to say that you heard the sound of *the meal itself*, not the sounds of cooking (the meal is currently being cooked, but that's a side-issue), then you would need to say something like:

> I heard the sound of the meal **which is** being cooked.

(Though I'm not really sure what sounds a meal would make by itself)

You are correct that your sentence #2 is weird.  In fact, it is actually just wrong (not grammatically correct, and makes no sense).